# Programmatically uploading and validating a user_picture

Tags: 8, users, files

I use the following code to modify the image in the `user_picture` field of user with uid 42:

```
// Get user.
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(42);

// Create file.
$file = file_save_data(
  file_get_contents('/tmp/image.jpg'),
  'public://pictures/image.jpg'
);

// Set file.
$user->set('user_picture', $file->id());

// Save user.
$user->save();
```

It works great, but it's very simplistic and doesn't do any of what has been configured in `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields/user.user.user_picture`, e.g:

- Validate "Allowed file extensions".
- Possibly downscale based on "Maximum image resolution".
- Save image in the "File directory" location.
- Validate "Maximum upload size".

Is there a way to somehow upload and set the file through what has been configured in the field?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the values of the image field settings with:

```
$user->getFieldDefinition('user_picture')->getSettings();
```

Which will return an array, example:

[image]

---

You then can use **[file_save_upload](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_save_upload/8.2.x)**

and you can pass to it for second param, an array containing all the validation functions

> array **$validators**: (optional) An associative array of callback
> functions used to validate the file. The keys are function names and
> the values arrays of callback parameters which will be passed in after
> the file entity. The functions should return an array of error
> messages; an empty array indicates that the file passed validation.
> The callback functions will be called in the order specified in the
> array, then the hook `hook_file_validate()` will be invoked so other
> modules can validate the new file.
>
> <sub>source: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_validate/8.9.x</sub>

Here are the validation functions you can use:

> [image]
>
> <sub>Source: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/8.9.x</sub>

Comment: Thanks. My file exists on disk but the first arg in `file_save_upload` regards an "upload form element" which I do not have.

Comment: @cherouvim usually you would create a form. But if you're just doing this programmatically without any UI for some reason, then keep doing it the way you're doing it and just pass the `$file` through all the validation functions and add a conditional to your save, so it only saves if it passes through all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Follow what [No Sssweat](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/27710/no-sssweat) said and as the documentation explains that "*The files will be added to the `file_managed` table as temporary files. Temporary files are periodically cleaned*" you'll need to set your file as permanent before to save it, else it will be erased during a cron task.

```
if ($file = file_save_upload($form_field_name, $validators, $destination, $delta, $replace)) {
  $file->setPermanent();
  $file->save();
}
```